# Optical Density numbers

Tags: biochemistry, spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

If it's OD of 600nm I know that's the wavelength used, but what are the other numbers in something like  "OD 600nm of 0.6-0.7". The 0.6-0.7?

Answer (score 3):

That is the optical density ([absorbance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbance)). It's just a range of between 0.6 and 0.7. Without the context, it's hard to say why they don't have a precise value, but in something like a protocol, it's common to see that kind of thing when there is some natural variation or the exact number isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

It's a (sloppy) spectroscopists' way to denote a concentration range *without* actually knowing it.

It happens when you don't start from a properly prepared stock solution and use an UV-VIS spectrometer instead of a balance. It typically goes like this:

1. Add some compound (tip of a spatulum) to a cuvette and dissolve it.
2. Measure the absorption. Typically it's much too high! ;)
3. Remove a part of the solution from the cuvette and add some solvent
4. Record the absorption spectrum again.

Repeat 3. and 4. until your absorption is in a medium range: far from saturation but still high enough to observe smaller signals (as the result of a possible reaction).